# Why is element.tagName undefined?

Tags: javascript

I was having a little play around this morning and I thought it would be fun to do something silly and try and write all the tagnames of a page on that page using something like this

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for(var element in elements) {

document.write(element.tagName + "<br />");

}
```

However all that gets written is undefined. Why is this? Oh and I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Even if `for...in` works, `element` would be the **index** of the entry, not the value. You'd have to write `elements[element].tagName`. `for` loop is better though. Read about `for...in`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for...in` is not guaranteed to work for a `NodeList` (which is what `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns), and even when it does, what you'll be getting as the value of `element` will be not be a reference to the element but rather a property name, such as the numeric index of the element in the `NodeList`. Use a normal `for` loop instead.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    document.write(elements[i].tagName + "<br />");
}
```

Also, `document.write()` won't work as you might expect after the document has loaded, which is when you'd typically use `document.getElementsByTagName()`. A better mechanism would be to populate an element in the page:

```
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Script:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var debugDiv = document.getElementById("debug");
var tagNames = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    tagNames.push(elements[i].tagName);
}

debugDiv.innerHTML = tagNames.join("<br>");
```

Comment: Better is to cache `length`. `elements` is a live collection.

Comment: @Felix: I usually do when appropriate. However, for the very reason that this list is live, it can be a mistake to cache the `length`, depending on what you do inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using a `for...in` loop, `element` is actually the item's key and not the value.  `elements[element]` would give you the correct result, but you should use a proper `for` loop instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    document.write(elements[i].tagName + "<br />");
}
```

This is because `for...in` may iterate over other enumerable properties that are not elements of the collection.  These properties can differ between browsers.

Comment: Better is to cache `length`. `elements` is a live collection.

Comment: @Felix: yeah, I just wrote it like that for brevity :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
     document.write(elements.item(i).tagName + "<br />");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is impossible, and is possible with jQuery/Sizzle HTML/CSS Selector:

```
$('*');
```

With that function/method you can only select "all available HTML tags" in your current document.

For example:

```
document.getElementByTagName('html');
document.getElementByTagName('head');
document.getElementByTagName('body');
document.getElementByTagName('h3');
document.getElementByTagName('p');
document.getElementByTagName('pre');
document.getElementByTagName('code');
document.getElementByTagName('metaforce'); // being a custom HTML(5) tag
```